# Cross domain issue when making ajax call from one site to another to get data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain

I am creating a site in which user can create popup on one site and then take small code to used on other site . Problem is when i am made ajax call from other site to fetch data in others site database i am getting error "No cross origin access allowed".When i am using jsonp it is giving me correct response but i am not able to collect it. It is giving me error"Unexpected token". I am using jquery ajax if you have any other idea then let me know i will implement it also. Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',

        data: {

            format: "json"
        },


    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the response look like? Is it JSON or JSONP formatted? They are not interchangeable without modifications to the server

Comment: Not all api's serve jsonp. Use a server side proxy either on your server or third party service. If you control the api...implement CORS

Comment: Sorry i am newbie in terms of API , Ajax , Json and Jsonp .  
This is my response when is use jsonp  "{"error":false,"message":"successful"} "   and in console error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Comment: I have full control on both servers because it is currently in testing phase @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

If Your response has error server side Cross domain issue then your server side response should  exist **Access-Controll-Allow-Origin** with * value will solve your problem.

Comment: I have added this code  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>   . But it didn't work

Comment: where is your server ? Is this locally or proxy ??

Comment: provide your response with header value . If you did not find header view on Postman (crome extension )

Comment: See i have two domains on two different servers. I have created api if post with two varaiables. It should fetch data otherwise dont.If data is fetched i will use it as i want. But the thing is jsonp giving error "uncaught syntax error" and i dont know any other way to get data from other site's database ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

crossDomain : true,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: 'callback',
  crossDomain : true,

    type: 'GET',

        data: {

            format: "json"
        },


    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

It solved my problem here.